# C# - Missing assembly/reference, Object-Oriented Programming

Tags: c#

I cannot seem to find the error to fix my code. I was given a tester class and was told to make the classes needed to run the tester properly. Here is the code i'm having a problem with:

**Tester Class**

```
using System;
using School;

namespace School
{
    class Tester
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Faculty scienceFac = University.createFaculty("Science");
        }
    }
}
```

**Faculty Class**

```
using System;

namespace School
{

public class Faculty
{
    public String faculty;

    public Faculty(String faculty)
    {
        this.faculty = faculty;
    }
}
}
```

**University Class**

```
using System;

namespace School
{

public class University
{
    private int numOfFaculties;

    public University()
    {
        numOfFaculties = 0;
    }

    public void createFaculty(String faculty)
    {
        numOfFaculties++;
        new Faculty(faculty);//?????
    }

    public int numberOfFaculties()
    {
        return numOfFaculties;  
    }
}
}
```

Only the tester shows an error, is it something I am referencing wrong with the namespaces?

Comment: sigh... take out the line that is different. (`using School;`)

Comment: "shows an error" - what *exactly* is the error? (And why are you calling a constructor without using the result?)

Comment: Additionally, you're calling `createFaculty` (which doesn't follow .NET naming conventions, btw) as if it's a static method, when it's not.

Comment: `new Faculty(faculty);//?????`  <- What do you intend to do with this line?

Comment: @Hogan doesn't do anything

Comment: @JonSkeet missing assembly/reference

Comment: @Khan I don't know, thats why I am wondering if thats a problem

Comment: @originalwill: That isn't *exactly* the error. If you look in Visual Studio, I very much doubt that the error list contains "missing assembly/reference" and nothing else. Copy and paste the exact error from VS.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the issues mentioned by other people in comments:

- The University class is "remembering" the number of faculties but not "remembering" the faculties themselves
- You don't need to initialise an integer *field* to 0
- There's no need to have a  `int numOfFaculties` field and a `int numberOfFaculties()` method - that's what properties are for: `public int NumberOfFaculties { get; private set; }` would do quite nicely.

---

I would suggest your `University` class needs to be something like this:

```
public class University
{
    private readonly List<Faculty> _faculties = new List<Faculty>();
    public List<Faculty> Faculties { get { return _faculties; } }

    public Faculty CreateFaculty(string facultyName)
    {
        var faculty = new Faculty(facultyName);
        _faculties.Add(faculty);
        return faculty;
    }

    public int NumberOfFaculties { get { return _faculties.Count; } }
}
```

Where `CreateFaculty()` creates a Faculty and *stores it in a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) inside the `University` object*, and where the `NumberOfFaculties` count is simply the [.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) of the list.

So to create a university with a science faculty you would call it like so:

```
University uni = new University();
Faculty scienceFac = uni.CreateFaculty("Science");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to change createFaculty to return the instance of Faculty.

```
public Faculty createFaculty(String faculty)
{
    numOfFaculties++;
    return new Faculty(faculty);
}
```

You also need to create an instance of University in your test project; createFaculty is not static.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var instance = new University();
    var scienceFac = instance.createFaculty("Science");
}
```